# save excel file using php

Tags: php, excel

How do I save an excel file while creating it without downloading?
I create the file in excel, while running that file the excel document l downloaded, I want to save that file without downloading options,

```
     Create that file automatically saved into that given path,
```

Comment: Sorry... what? You want to save a file on the **user's** computer *without* a download dialog popping up?

Comment: yes... i want to do that, without that dialog box. Yeah, just create the excel document and saved in that file location

Comment: Think about what people would do if that were possible. You'd have your computer hijacked by a virus on every webpage you viewed. Anyone could download viruses, malware, porn onto your computer without you having any say.

Comment: I think u r not understand my query, coz of my language is not clear, thats my fault, but i ll do a solution for that, i ll get back to u soon... I can do... Thanks for ur help....

Comment: The question you seem to have right now is *"Can a website save a file on the user's computer without any user interaction?"* If so, @Dan's comment is spot on. If that's not your question, you indeed need to clarify a lot.

Comment: no, i have generate the excel file and saved into server, afterthat i ll send a email that file, thats y am asking, if possible to generate and send email the excel file?

Comment: Then this is a terribly misleading question, as it has nothing to do with downloading, and you're not even mentioning "mail" at all. Voting to close as possible duplicate of [Generate And Email Excel File using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779250/generate-and-email-excel-file-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. Through a normal browser, you have no direct access to a user's file system. And that's a good thing. Think security for a second.

You'd have to write a Java, ActiveX (Internet Explorer) or other sort of plugin and get the user to install that first, before you have any direct access to the user's computer. Without this, the user will have to confirm all file downloads.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers don't allow web sites to directly write files to the clients filesystem.

It may be possible to write a browser plugin to accomplish this but it would be hard to convince most visitors to your site to install the plugin. There would be a support overhead to keep the plugin up to date with all supported browsers.

If you are on an intranet, you could write the file to a shared drive.

Comment: If this was for an intranet, a plugin may actually be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure who your target audience is, but if this is an internal app you do have other options.  You could have the user install Dropbox or a similar file-sharing application and then from your server update the files on Dropbox, which would add/update the local file on the user's dropbox folder soon after.

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel does exactly what your are asking for :

> Project providing a set of classes for the PHP programming language,
>   which allow you to write to and read from different file for

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

Try this Report It automatically stored in our script running location

http://smartcoderszone.com/2010/09/how-to-generate-excel-report-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259